# Slightly broken SD card is not readable on macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, sd-card

I put the SD card (sandisk ultra 32gb) in the card slot in macbook pro. But it is not getting detected. When I tried to find on Disk utility it doesnt show up. I have very important data in the SD card which I am not able to procure. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try using it on a different computer.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no such thing as 'slightly broken' when it comes to electronics.

If it's just the contacts, it may be possible to replace them. If you cracked the circuit board, then at best you will have to send it to a professional data recovery company, who will be expensive & make no guarantees of recovery.

At worst, you now know why it is extremely unwise to ever trust something as delicate as an SD card or USB stick to be a repository for the only copy of any data. No important data should ever be kept in only one place, two at minimum & three to be sure; the third not in the same building as the other two.

Comment: I did my final year project back in the days of 3.5" floppies - pile of 4 disks and rotated through the pile so had multiple copies... soon as 1 disk errored > bin...

Comment: @SolarMike - I haven't trusted data to a floppy since the mid 80s. By 87 I had HDs, by 93 I had CD & then tape backups too. 92 was the last time I had data in only one place. For the past 20 years I've always had an absolute minimum of one onsite & one off site backup, which these days is local HD & one or two cloud structures; maximum total data loss in a fire, 24 hours. I once lost a file. It won't happen again ;-)

Comment: I was the first among those who had an Atari ST to fit a hard drive, back then the price was 25 times the size in MB so a 10MB hard drive cost me over 250... And I totally agree, multiple copies in multiple places. The **pain** of loosing stuff.

Comment: I had a 650MB external SCSI [+ adapter] drive on an ST... £850 at the time. It was bigger than the computer. How things have moved on ;-))

Comment: Still remember the Atari fondly - got my Mum once - set it to play "Okey-Dokey" every time the enter key was pressed. She nearly fell of the chair !!